# weak solution of Dirichlet problem in Lipschtiz domain with non zero boundary data

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega$ a bounded and open with Lipschitz boundary. I know that exists the trace operator in the case of  this $\Omega$. My question is :

When $\Omega$ is bounded and open with Lipschitz boundary, the problem

$$ \left\{ \begin{array}{ccccccc}
 -\Delta u  = 0 ,  \  in  \ \Omega   \\ \ u=g , \ in \ \partial\Omega \\ \end{array} \right. $$

have unique solution $u \in H^{1}(\Omega)$? (the equation is in the weak sense and the boundary condition is in the sense of the trace operator, that is , $g$ is in the image of the trace operator)

I dont found a book talking about of this problem in the case of Lipschitz boudary and  nonzero boundary data.

Someone know a book with the answer ? (I believe the answer is yes  because of the existence of the trace operator in this case)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: In order to get a unique solution you need to specify two things: 1. Unique in which space? $H^1_0(\Omega)$ or some space of smoother functions? 2. Where does $g$ belong? $H^{-1}(\partial\Omega)$?

Comment: You're right. I forget to write these details . sorry for i forget (my english is terrible , sorry) . i writed  better the question

Comment: Have you tried to prove it? Hint: minimize the functional $I(u)=\int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2$ restricted to the set $\mathcal{K}=\{u\in H^1(\Omega):\ Tu=g\}$ where $T$ is the trace operator. I could not find it now, but I have answered this question somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $g\in H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega)$ you have uniqueness in $H^1(\Omega)$, provided that $\partial\Omega$ satisfies the cone condition - Lipschitz condition is even stronger, so with Lipschitz domains you also have uniqueness.

Comment: but every function of $L^2 (\partial \Omega)$ is in the image of the trace operator ?

Comment: No, the image of $T$ is $H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega)$, which is a proper subset of $L^2(\partial\Omega)$